# Invoking PowerShell script as other user from inside Java

Tags: java, powershell

I've got a chain of scripts that work as expected when invoked from the command line, but if the same user is running TomCat as a service under the same account `Start-Process` appears to return without doing anything.

My question is, is there something inherently different the environment built during a command executed from Java?  Any pointers would be helpful.

**Invocation from Command Line**

If I issue the command **`cmd /c c:\test\test.bat`** when logged in as cuser1 at a non-elevated command prompt, I see the following log:

```
HS0\cuser1 called script as HS0\cuser2
Script running as HS0\cuser2
```

**Invocation from Java Process**

If I issue the same command using **`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`** from inside my TomCat application, I don't see the switch.

```
List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<>();
cmd.add("cmd");
cmd.add("/c");
cmd.add("C:\\test\\test.bat");
final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
...
// Handling the command output, nothing in the output, no error result
```

Instead, I only see the first line of the log.  I've been catching exceptions, looking at exceptions and reading the output of the command, but it appears that the `Start-Process` command returns immediately without an error code.  This is obviously test code with hardcoded credentials and not the real deal, but I can see the same behavior in this simplified code.

**The Test**

```
c:\test\test.bat => calls a PowerShell script
c:\test\test-switch.ps1 => invokes a PowerShell script as different user
c:\test\test.ps1 => display current user
```

*test.bat*

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "c:\test\test-switch.ps1"
```

*test-switch.ps1*

```
$currentUser = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -asplaintext -force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("HS0\cuser2", $pwd)
$args = "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File c:\test\test.ps1"
Start-Process Powershell -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $args
"$currentUser called script as HS0\cuser2"  | Out-File 'c:\test\test.log' -Append
```

*test.ps1*

```
$currentUser = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
"Script running at $(Get-Date) as $currentUser"  | Out-File 'c:\test\test.log' -Append
```

Comment: So your PowerShell script is started but `Start-Process` doesn't do anything? Did you try to write to another file? Can you confirm that `$currentUser` is valid in both scripts? I could imagine that `%path%` is unavailable in tomcat context and Powershell can't be found.

Comment: Additional information: I checked your scripts in jshell and they worked. If it's not an only-java8-problem (which I don't guess), it definitely relates to tomcat than java itself.

Comment: A couple of things I've tried or confirmed.  1) I wrote to two different files, to make sure it wasn't a concurrency issue. 2) I validated that the current user is set in the beginning of each script.  3) I used full path to PowerShell.exe.